# Image Classification CNN save best parameters with ModelCheckpoint

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am doing image classification with CNN.

The following is my model:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))


model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=16,batch_size=64,validation_data=(x_val,y_val))
```

The epoch results are like the below:

```
Epoch 1/16
416/416 [==============================] - 832s 2s/step - loss: 0.7742 - accuracy: 0.8689 - val_loss: 0.5149 - val_accuracy: 0.8451
Epoch 2/16
416/416 [==============================] - 825s 2s/step - loss: 0.5608 - accuracy: 0.8585 - val_loss: 0.3776 - val_accuracy: 0.8808
Epoch 3/16
416/416 [==============================] - 775s 2s/step - loss: 0.1926 - accuracy: 0.9338 - val_loss: 0.3328 - val_accuracy: 0.9066
Epoch 4/16
416/416 [==============================] - 587s 1s/step - loss: 0.0984 - accuracy: 0.9650 - val_loss: 0.3163 - val_accuracy: 0.9388
Epoch 5/16
416/416 [==============================] - 578s 1s/step - loss: 0.0606 - accuracy: 0.9798 - val_loss: 0.3584 - val_accuracy: 0.9357
Epoch 6/16
416/416 [==============================] - 511s 1s/step - loss: 0.0457 - accuracy: 0.9860 - val_loss: 0.5067 - val_accuracy: 0.9360
Epoch 7/16
416/416 [==============================] - 476s 1s/step - loss: 0.3649 - accuracy: 0.8912 - val_loss: 0.4446 - val_accuracy: 0.8645
Epoch 8/16
416/416 [==============================] - 476s 1s/step - loss: 0.3108 - accuracy: 0.9006 - val_loss: 0.6096 - val_accuracy: 0.8681
Epoch 9/16
416/416 [==============================] - 477s 1s/step - loss: 0.2397 - accuracy: 0.9158 - val_loss: 0.4061 - val_accuracy: 0.9042
Epoch 10/16
416/416 [==============================] - 502s 1s/step - loss: 0.1334 - accuracy: 0.9532 - val_loss: 0.3673 - val_accuracy: 0.9281
Epoch 11/16
416/416 [==============================] - 478s 1s/step - loss: 0.2787 - accuracy: 0.9184 - val_loss: 0.6745 - val_accuracy: 0.9039
Epoch 12/16
416/416 [==============================] - 481s 1s/step - loss: 0.7476 - accuracy: 0.8649 - val_loss: 0.4643 - val_accuracy: 0.8777
Epoch 13/16
416/416 [==============================] - 488s 1s/step - loss: 0.2187 - accuracy: 0.9271 - val_loss: 0.3347 - val_accuracy: 0.9102
Epoch 14/16
416/416 [==============================] - 483s 1s/step - loss: 4.0347 - accuracy: 0.9171 - val_loss: 0.6267 - val_accuracy: 0.7980
Epoch 15/16
416/416 [==============================] - 476s 1s/step - loss: 0.5838 - accuracy: 0.8095 - val_loss: 0.4481 - val_accuracy: 0.8663
Epoch 16/16
416/416 [==============================] - 492s 1s/step - loss: 0.4916 - accuracy: 0.8520 - val_loss: 1.0406 - val_accuracy: 0.6113
```

My first question is that because the mode.fit will keep the last epoch result, but my last epoch result is not the best(the epoch 4/16 is the best result based on min val_loss)

Hence, I wonder how could I build on a model using the epoch 4/16 parameter?

Note: I have saved the model.

I realize that if I add ModelCheckpoing in the model.fit, then the min val_loss may be saved. However, because it takes me a long time to run the code, I think is it possible to extract the min val_loss result directly from the model I saved without running the code again?

My second question is that I do not understand how ModelCheckpoint works since my understanding is that ModelCheckpoint will stop at the best epoch.

if I have a ModelCheckpoint like below:

```
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True)
```

If the epoch is 16 and the min val_loss happened at epoch 4/16, then using the ModelCheckpoing will stop running the code at epoch 4/16 and save the parameters. But it does not run the rest of the epoch 5 to 16, how does it know that epoch 4 is the best? or actually, using ModelCehckpoint, the code will still run the 16 epoch and just save the best one(epoch 4)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelCheckpoint does not stop the training. After each epoch it compares the result with the current best one, and pick the best between two, according to this [document code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1205), then you only need to reload the saved model to get that best weight.

Comment: Thanks AeryS.
So if I save the model as 'best_model.h5'.
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', mode='min',save_best_only=True).
and I do the mode.fit(callbacks = [mc])
then the model would use the parameters of epoch 4 (min val_loss) ?

Comment: Yes, it only saves the model when the monitored value is best, in your case at epoch 4.

Comment: But I have to run the code again right because when I first save  'best_model.h5', I did not specify the callbacks. ( which means I save the 'best_model.h5' with the last epoch parameters) In this case, it wont work even if I specify the callbacks argument with 'best_model.h5'.

Comment: Yeah you cannot turn back if you do not use any callback.

Comment: Hi, if you find my answer is acceptable, consider: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers